# C linter for endif comments

Tags: c, lint

I work on a code base in C that follows the common practice of annotating `#else` and `#endif` preprocessor directives with the condition. For example:

```
#if FOO
…
#if BAR
…
#endif /* BAR */
…
#endif /* FOO */
```

Unfortunately, over time, these comments tend to bitrot when we change a `#if` but forget to change the matching `#endif`, so we end up with misleading code:

```
#if FOO
…
#if BAR && BAZ
…
#endif /* BAR */
…
#endif /* FOO */
```

This is low-level embedded code, so there's a lot of conditional compilation. We're considering changing our policy to remove all such comments and rely on editor navigation. But when they're correct, these comments do help readability. So we'd prefer to keep them, but we want them to be correct.

Thus I'm looking for a **tool that detects incorrect `#else` and `#endif` comments**. It should accept the first snippet above, and complain about the second snippet because `BAR && BAZ` doesn't match `BAR`.

Required:

- Support `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#endif` and `#else` directives.
- Support backslash continuation lines.
- Complain if a comment on `#else` or `#endif` doesn't match the previous `#if…`
- Run on Linux.
- Can run in a CI script (not an editor plugin).
- Free for commercial use.

Preferably, but not required:

- The proper comment can be a complicated matter when there are `#elif` directives. The tool should have sensible requirements there. We can change our convention to match the tool if needed.
- Ignore `#endif` that doesn't have a comment, because we tend not to put comments when the `#endif` is very close to the `#if`.
- Allow `FOO` to match `defined(FOO)`.
- Support both `/* … */` and `//` comments.
- Whitespace should not matter.
- Support `#endif /* dir/filename.h */` rather than `#endif /* DIR_FILENAME_H */` for `#ifndef DIR_FILENAME_H` (a common convention for header include guards).
- Allow some form of free-form comment if it's “obvious” (for some sensible definition of obvious) that the comment is not intended to match the original condition. For example:

  ```
  #if UINT_MAX == 0xffff
    // 16-bit optimized code
  #elif UINT_MAX == 0xffffffff
    // 32-bit optimized code
  #elif UINT_MAX == 0xffffffffffffffff
    // 64-bit optimized code
  #else /* weird word size */
    //
  #endif /* word size */
  ```

  It's ok if this involves placing a specific annotation in the comment.
- Ideally, avoid dependencies other than standard GNU tools, GCC, Clang, Perl and Python. Any dependency that isn't distributed in Ubuntu would be an additional pain point.
- FOSS.

I couldn't find anything relevant in [Lint](https://invisible-island.net/personal/lint-tools.html), [Splint](http://splint.org/), GCC or Clang warnings, clang-tidy or clang-format, by searching Ubuntu packages, or in a web search.

Answer (score 1):

CLion from JetBrains does this:

[image: ifdef]

PS: Like you, I'm curious to see what else does, as a CLI tool would be preferred.